# Putting records to the top based on where clause in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I am developing an Asp.net mvc project using Entity Framework. I am trying to order the record by where clause.

This is my query:

```
this.BloodDonations.Where(x => x.Blood == BloodType.A);
```

The above query will retrieve all the blood donations where type is A. But I want to retrieve the record sending the ones with type A to the top and the rest goes after A. How can I sort it based on `Where` clause?

Comment: You need an `.OrderBy()`, not a `.Where()`

Answer (score 0):

Instead use Orderby if you require to sort in ascending order(A to Z).

```
this.BloodDonations.OrderBy(x => x.Blood);
```

To orderby descending(Z to A):

```
this.BloodDonations.OrderByDescending(x => x.Blood);
```